# How to override Kendo Grid keyboard navigation?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I need to overwrite some of the Kendo UI Grid's keyboard navigation, such as Ctrl+End, that focuses on the last row's last cell and I need to override that so when I click Ctrl+End that I can focus on whichever cell that I want, but I have to keep the navigation property set to true because I am also tabbing through the grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you'll have to implement your own navigation with the help of the [current](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/methods/current) method.

The grid exposes a [navigate](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/events/navigate) event, and you could do preventDefault on it, but id doesn't tell you what keys were pressed for the navigation.

Comment: I do have my own custom navigation, but I was missing the currentCell method. Thank you for pointing that out